# Definition for what is on/off topic

Tags: discussion, scope, off-topic, questions

I am fairly new to this site, but have been answering questions for the past 2 weeks.

I would like to know where i can find out what is on/off topic?

As a fitness Professional you get asked all sorts of fitness related question.  I always try to give an answer if I am confident I know it.   If I don't Know I refer them to who I feel would best help.

The last couple of days I have come across a couple of questions, that I would most certainly of answered if they had been from clients face to face, but they have comments against them saying they are off topic without any suggestions as to where they might get the answer.

I feel that if we are trying to get more people to post, even if questions are off topic, we should tread a little more gently in saying so, and at the very least suggest where they can get the information, or where best to find their answer.  We do want these people to come back and ask more questions after all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so with a bit of routing around I found my answer!
https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

I will leave question rather than deleting, in case anyone else finds it helpful

I still feel we need to tread more carefully when saying things are off topic